# How Can I compare the microsoft word file with it previous version programatically? need the output like git compare of file

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-online, filecompare

I want to compare the word file with it previous version in sharepoint online. either by power automate or by programatically. I used encodian connector and able to compare however it is paid tool so need open source solution. for same. need the output like git compare of code file or as attached image.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, there isn't an easy way to do this. For example, look at WinMerge https://github.com/winmerge/winmerge.
Although it's written in C++ you can see that it's a pretty involved process